# Vim: Clone a Buffer and Make It Hidden

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

How do I create a new buffer as a clone of another buffer? In other words, the contents should be the same, but these should be 2 distinct buffers in the end. I'm more interested in programmatic way of doing this, rather than from the point of view of mappings, as this is needed for the future plugin.

Recommendations like yanking one buffer, then giving focus to another one and pasting wouldn't work here since it would mean that we've overwritten user's previous yank and therefore spoiled user's experience after the invocation of our plugin method. I'm looking for some way to do it as sneaky as possible.

Furthermore, as a bonus, this new buffer should be created hidden because it will be used just to store some processed data quickly and then die immediately. Preferably, this should be done **without** any splits as they will introduce annoying blinking (because of Vim redrawing the screen) even if closed as soon as possible (for example, `:new`/`:close` combo). We also **cannot** assume that the buffer which we want to clone has a name.

Thank you.

### Conclusion

---

Some testing revealed that transferring data with

```
:put=getbufline(...)
```

is the fastest method, and the most secure one since it does not interfere with user experience in any way.

Although, nobody answered on this, I've managed to find a function which will create a new hidden buffer without any splits, i.e. it will be created silently on the background with no window. To learn more see `:h bufnr()`. Example:

```
let buffer_number = bufnr('My New Hidden Buffer', 1)
```

Furthermore, this call will implicitly do the following:

```
let &l:buflisted = 0
```

on this newly created buffer, so it will be also hidden from `:ls`, which is exactly what we need to satisfy above requirements.

As a result, there will be no blinking or any visual irritation for the user like from `:new`/`:close` combo... a truly hidden buffer for some dirty work.

Comment: You can save the yank register in a local variable then restore it at the end of your function

Comment: @FDinoff: This is something I've been looking for. Will it really save the whole yank, no matter how big it is?

Comment: To save the contents of the quote register do `let saved = @"` and then at the end of the function restore it with `let @" = saved`. The whole contents of the register will be saved. To the user it will be like nothing ever changed.

Comment: @Haroogan Interesting. Feel free to post your own answer and accept it. For the record, no, I don't have `'lazyredraw'` set but I didn't ever experience any "blinking" with `:new`, neither in GVim/MacVim nor in terminal Vim.

Comment: @glts: I'll leave your answer as the accepted one since this data transfer method turned out to be very useful, thanks again for that. The example when you would see the blinking would be when the time between `:new` and `:close` calls is relatively long enough because of, for instance, some heavy operations in between. Then you'd definitely notice this quick split and death of the window as a blink. Just for the record, I'm currently testing on Windows. Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a function for this called `getbufline()`. Look up [`:h getbufline()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#getbufline%28%29).

Here it is in action, incorporated into this clone command:

```
:new | put =getbufline('#',1,'$') | 1d_
```

This clones the current buffer into a new split.

Notes:

- The vertical [`<Bar>`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#%3abar) chains Ex commands, in this case three of them;
- [`:new`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#%3anew) creates a new buffer in a split window and moves the focus there;
- [`:put =`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#%3aput) evaluates the expression passed to it and inserts items from a list as lines;
- `getbufline()` is called to read lines from start `1` to finish `'$'` from the "alternate file" `'#'`;
- `:1d_` gets rid of the empty line 1 produced as a side effect by `:put`.

For your convenience, here is the command again, packaged as the user command `:Clone`.

```
:command! Clone new | put =getbufline('#',1,'$') | 1d_
```

Comment: Nice variant, many thanks! The only thing that's left and I can't find it anywhere is how to prevent the buffer from being shown. Unfortunately, it seems like it's impossible.

Comment: Easy: add `| close` at the end.

Comment: Yeah, but there will be a nasty blink, and furthermore after closing it, can I do any operations with it? Like, for example, copying its content to another buffer again?

Comment: @Haroogan Now you're asking how to write a plugin with splits! That's a bit too big a question. I think if you really want to do serious window-splitting and buffer-manhandling in a Vim plugin you need to learn from the masters: read the source for Gundo, NERDTree, Tagbar, etc. etc.

Comment: Not with splits, I don't need any splits. All I want is to create a hidden buffer to do some work on it and kill it, but without any visual irritation. I think it was stated clearly in the question.

Comment: @Haroogan I don't get any blinking, the command is silent for me. You can do any sort of work on the cloned buffer just after the `:put` command, e.g. add `| 1,5d | %s/foo/bar/g | g/baz/d | ...`. And then save it and `:bdelete` it in the end.

Comment: Maybe the 'lazyredraw' option prevents the blink?

Comment: @Ben, glts: I've tried `lazyredraw` already, but it changes nothing. Nevertheless, I've managed to achieve what I wanted: see my original post for the corresponding update.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `let var=getline(1,'$')` to get all lines in a buffer and put them into a variable. Then you can either use the data directly in a list, or you can use the `append()` or `setline()` functions to write that text in another buffer. If you want the data in a file to process externally, you can use the `writefile()` function.

Or, you can write to a file using `:w newfilename` and if the current buffer already has a file name associated, this will just create a new file with the current buffer content without changing the associated file at all. You can then open that file or use the `readfile()` function to get the text into Vim. If your processing occurs outside of Vim, this may be the better option because it doesn't involve keeping a lot of data in a list or opening a new buffer.

Comment: Updated, take a look if you are interested in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, your buffer already has a name? Then here is another approach:

`:sp|f foobar|exe "norm! \<C-^>"`

`:sp` splits the buffer

`:f foobar` set's the buffer name for both split windows to foobar (and sets the old buffername to the alternate file)

`exe "norm! \<C-^>"` switches in the current window to the previous buffer

Comment: Updated, take a look if you are interested in the solution.

Comment: I think, you might be even better off, with using something as simple as `:f foobar`

Comment: You seem to be missing something. The whole point of the `:f` command is to
**clone** an existing buffer. You don't need to create a new buffer and fill it manually, because :f **does this already**,
including local option values, buffer variables and ending style.

Here is an example for you:
```
    ~$ vim -u NONE -N ~/.vimrc
    :echo bufnr('%')
    1
    :let b:bufname=bufname('%')
    :f foobar
    :echo "this is buffer: " bufnr('%') b:bufname
    this is buffer: 1 /home/christian/.vimrc
    :q!
    ~$
````

I think, now it is time, to apologize for your inappropriate comment.